# Change only specific href name on hover jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
<td><a href="Wizyty-proces.php?status=<?php echo $row['idwizyty']; ?>" class="status">
 <?php echo $row['status'];?></a></td>
```

```
var elem = $('.status'), orig = elem.text();
    elem.hover(
    function() { $(this).text('End'); },
    function() { $(this).text(orig); }
);
```

Is there a way to change the href name only when the name of href is 'Waiting'?
I'm looping through my database and $row['status'] is either 'Waiting' or 'Done'.
I want to change name of href on hover to 'End' only when it equals 'Waiting'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a property in your link that helps you get the links you want, something like:

```
<a href="Wizyty-proces.php?status=<?php echo $row['idwizyty']; ?>" data-status="<?php echo $row['idwizyty']; ?>" class="status">Link </a>
```

And in your js/jquery script, you can get the elements with the specified status with something like this:

```
var element = $('.status').filter('[data-status="waiting"]')
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: it helped me. Thank you!